# How to check if field type is date in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check field types and I can do this for every field type but date.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mh4rwy78/

html:

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="date">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="check" href="#">check</a>
```

Js:

```
$( '.check').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $( '.field input' ).each(function(index, value) {
        if( $(this).is(':date') ) {
          alert('date-found');
        }
      });
    });
```

If I change it to the following it works:

```
$( '.check').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $( '.field input' ).each(function(index, value) {
    if( $(this).is(':text') ) {
      alert('date-found');
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried :date and just date, Googling hasn't come up with an answer (so far).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use: `$(this).is('[type="date"]')` instead of `$(this).is(':date')`

Comment: You could also make your own jQuery selector `:date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selector `[type="date"]`

```
$( '.check').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $( '.field input' ).each(function(index, value) {
  if( $(this).is('[type="date"]') ) {
    alert('date-found');
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `:date` is still not available inside the [jQuery selectors Extensions](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/),
you could always use good old vanilla `this.type === "date"`. It's faster than going back to `$(this).is(` since you're accessing directly the Element Properties.

```js
$('.check').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.field input').each(function() {
    if (this.type === "date") {
      console.log('date-found ' + this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="date">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="check" href="#">check</a>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Make your own jQuery Selector:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  date(el) { return el.type === "date"; }
});

$('.check').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.field input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":date")) {
      console.log('date-found ' + this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="date">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="check" href="#">check</a>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```